# (Dis)prove: $\left\lceil\frac{\left\lceil\frac{x}2\right\rceil}2\right\rceil=\left\lceil\frac{x}4\right\rceil\ \forall x\in\Bbb R$

Tags: proof-writing, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I don't how to prove if $\frac{x}2\in\Bbb Z$.

Let  $\frac{x}2=n\in\Bbb Z$.

$\begin{aligned}\left\lceil\frac{\left\lceil\frac{x}2\right\rceil}2\right\rceil&=\left\lceil\frac{x}4\right\rceil\\\left\lceil\frac{n}2\right\rceil&=\left\lceil\frac{x}2\cdot\frac12\right\rceil\\\left\lceil\frac{n}2\right\rceil&=\left\lceil\frac{n}2\right\rceil\end{aligned}$

Let $\frac{x}2, b\in\Bbb R,\ 0<b<1,\ a\in\Bbb Z$.

$m=a+b$

case 1:  $0<b<0.5$

$0<b/2<0.25$

$\left\lceil\frac{\lceil a+b\rceil}2\right\rceil=\left\lceil\frac{a+b}2\right\rceil$
What should $\frac{a}2$ be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $x=4m-a$ with $m\in\Bbb Z$ and $a\in[0,4)$.
Then $$\left\lceil\frac x4\right\rceil =\left\lceil m-\frac a4\right\rceil =m,$$
$$\left\lceil\frac x2\right\rceil =\left\lceil 2m-\frac a2\right\rceil =\begin{cases}2m&0\le a<2\\2m-1&2\le a<4\,\end{cases}$$
and so 
$$ \left\lceil\frac{ \left\lceil\frac x2\right\rceil}2\right\rceil=\left\lceil m\quad\textit{or}\quad m-\frac12\right\rceil=m$$

Comment: Thanks,it is amazing but is it possible to know that 4m-a can represent all the real number x?

Comment: @LeeSam to disprove, we only need to show that the equation is not true for some real number $x$

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja if we cannot disprove,it doesn't mean the equation is true,it may be we cannot find the counter example,so how can we prove this equation is true?